# What's the correct way to display db results in a shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know I'm not supposed to echo anything in a shortcode function, but I don't understand the correct way to do this. I see people asking this question but no one seemed to know the answer.

```
// my shortcode function

 function simpledir_shortcode_list() { 

    // get list of items in directory

    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_simpledir LIMIT 10');

    ?> 

        <?php
        $count = 1;
        foreach ( $result as $listing )
        { 
            if ($count % 2 == 0) { ?>

             <div class="alternate" valign="top"> 


            <?php }else{ ?>

                 <div valign="top"> 

            <?php
            }
            ?>

                    <div class="listing-item">
                        <p><?= $listing->name; ?></p>
                    </div>

        <?php 
            $count++;
            }
        ?>

        </div>    
<?php } 

add_shortcode('simpledir_shortcode_list','simpledir_shortcode_list');

?>
```

If I use [simpledir_shortcode_list] on any page of course Wordpress gives an error, but What is the steps one would output database results properly even though this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to **return** the output instead of **display** it. To do so, you can store everything in a variable and return just that:

```
// my shortcode function
function simpledir_shortcode_list() {

    // get list of items in directory

    global $wpdb;

    $output = '';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_simpledir LIMIT 10');

    $count = 1;

    foreach ( $result as $listing )
    {
        if ($count % 2 == 0) {
            $output .= '<div class="alternate" valign="top">';
        } else {
            $output .= '<div valign="top">';
        }

        $output .= '<div class="listing-item"><p>' . $listing->name . '</p></div>';

        $count++;
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;

}
add_shortcode('simpledir_shortcode_list', 'simpledir_shortcode_list');
```

---

By the way, it seems that your closing `</div>` tag should be inside the `foreach` loop instead of outside as you have it now:

```
// my shortcode function
function simpledir_shortcode_list() {

    // get list of items in directory

    global $wpdb;

    $output = '';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_simpledir LIMIT 10');

    $count = 1;

    foreach ( $result as $listing )
    {
        if ($count % 2 == 0) {
            $output .= '<div class="alternate" valign="top">';
        } else {
            $output .= '<div valign="top">';
        }

        $output .= '<div class="listing-item"><p>' . $listing->name . '</p></div>';

        $output .= '</div>';

        $count++;
    }

    return $output;

}
add_shortcode('simpledir_shortcode_list', 'simpledir_shortcode_list');
```